# Fixing ylabel location in a colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib in python to create a covariance plot using color bar. But the problem is that ylabel is drawn over the color bar axis. I'm unable to find how to solve this.

Here's an example:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
def create_covariance_plot(X, name):
    """
    Visualizes the covariance matrix for a design matrix.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    X:a design matrix where each column is a feature and each row is an observation.
    name: the name of the plot.
    """
    pylab.figure()
    n_cols = X.shape[1]
    X = X.T
    R = np.corrcoef(X)
    pylab.pcolor(R)
    cb = pylab.colorbar()
    cb.ax.set_ylabel('Correlation Strength', rotation=270)
    pylab.yticks(np.arange(0, n_cols + 0.5),range(0,n_cols))
    pylab.xticks(np.arange(0, n_cols + 0.5),range(0,n_cols))
    pylab.xlim(0, n_cols)
    pylab.ylim(0, n_cols)
    pylab.xlabel("Feature")
    pylab.ylabel("Feature")
    pylab.savefig(name + ".png")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to

```
cb.ax.set_ylabel('Correlation Strength', rotation=270, labelpad=25)
```

In general, you should expect the convenience functions to do a "best guess" approach, and you can always specify precise axes, labels etc., positions using the more general functions, in this case probably figtext.